# RavenDB - Build a dynamic query with OR filters

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I need to be able to build a query at runtime that uses OR statments.  If I use the method below to build the query, everything is AND together.  I really need each filter value to be OR in order for this query to work correctly.

```
public class IdAndRole
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Role {get;set;}
}

var idAndRoles = session.Query<IdAndRole, Roles_ById>();
foreach(var filter in filterValues)
{
    idAndRoles = idAndRoles.Where(x => x.In(filter.Id) && x.In(filter.Role));
}
```

Pseudocode:

```
(filter[0].Id == value1 && filter[0].Role == role1) ||(filter[1].Id == value2 && filter[1].Role == role2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phil,
You can drop down into the LuceneQuery, and that allows you fine grained control over your query.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use a [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to construct the query.

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<IdAndRole>();
foreach (var filter in filterValues)
{
     predicate = predicate.Or( x => x.In(filter.Id) && x.In(filter.Role) );
}

var idAndRoles = session.Query<IdAndRole,Roles_byId>()
                        .Where( predicate );
```

Comment: This is specific to the RavenDB Linq provider. The Predicate Builder does not exists in RavenDB

Comment: @Phil - no, but you can get the source.  It builds an Expression that ought to work just fine.  I'm using some similar techniques to build up expressions in one of my RavenDB projects.